# Expanding/Sharing root with another ssd (Hybrid mounting?)

Tags: partitioning, ssd, udisks

I just installed a new ssd and I've been trying to figure out the best way to partition it so it can be used as an expansion to root while also still being accessed like a different mounted drive or folder. I want to be able to share the root folder in a way that avoids conflicts if I, for example, move all my flatpaks and vm drives over to the new ssd, it will act like nothing happens. Is there some specific way I need to partition it and can it be done with the built in UDisks utility?

Comment: If you have used LVM in your installation then it is easy. Just add as much or as little of your new ssd to the VolumeGroup and keep some back for a partition to mount separately. If you haven’t used LVM then you can reinstall.

Comment: This is a problem. My original partition is not an LVM partition nor does my install have a volume group. Please tell me there's an alternative. I really don't need to pull my hair out for this.

Comment: If the majority of your data is within /home then an alternative solution is to move the location of /home to a partition on the new SSD. You can certainly store VM disks there. Don’t use Flatpacks myself to be able to advise. There are answered questions on here that tell you how to do that, just search for them.